# Swift 3: append characters to an Array

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a Swift 3 array that's initialized with the following:

`var foo: [String] = []`

In one of my methods that gets invoked recursively, I'm attempting to convert a string into an array of characters, but append those characters versus doing a direct assignment to `foo`. So this will compile:

`self.foo = text.characters.map { String($0) }`

But the following breaks:

`self.foo.append(text.characters.map { String($0) })`

The error it produces is:  `'map' produces '[T]', not expected contextual result type 'String'`

What's the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Swift is dumb. When it says `[T]`, it means `[String]`. You can't append `[String]` to `[String]`, you can only append `String` or append the contents of `[String]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be using the [`append(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2854129-append) method instead.

```
foo.append(contentsOf: text.characters.map { String($0) })
```

This method can take an array of the defined type.

Whereas the [`append()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538872-append) method expects a single element to add at the end of the array.